# Media query and page width in Bootstrap based Moodle theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, media-queries, moodle

I'm using the LMS Moodle 4 and the bootstrap based theme boost ([github](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/master/theme/boost/scss/bootstrap))

By default the page is very narrow on all screens and I'd like to use the bootstrap approach for different screen sizes ([.container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/))

This is what I tried to use in the raw scss field and also the custom css field:

```
/* Page Width */
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) { $course-content-maxwidth: 100% !default; }
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) { $course-content-maxwidth: 540px !default; }
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { $course-content-maxwidth: 720px !default; }
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { $course-content-maxwidth: 960px !default; }
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399px) { $course-content-maxwidth: 1140px !default; }
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) { $course-content-maxwidth: 1320px !default; }
```

When I only use

```
$course-content-maxwidth: 100% !default;
```

or

```
$course-content-maxwidth: 1320px !default;
```

it does work but not the combination with media queries above.

Any idea how I could get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I used the variable wrong. When I use classes it works:

```
/* Page Width */
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) { .pagelayout-standard #page.drawers .main-inner, body.limitedwidth #page.drawers .main-inner { max-width: 540px; }}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { .pagelayout-standard #page.drawers .main-inner, body.limitedwidth #page.drawers .main-inner { max-width: 720px; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { .pagelayout-standard #page.drawers .main-inner, body.limitedwidth #page.drawers .main-inner { max-width: 960px; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399px) { .pagelayout-standard #page.drawers .main-inner, body.limitedwidth #page.drawers .main-inner { max-width: 1140px; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) { .pagelayout-standard #page.drawers .main-inner, body.limitedwidth #page.drawers .main-inner { max-width: 1320px; } }
```